# Filter action events not accurate

Tags: google-apps-activity

Have there been any changes to Google Drive Activity Queries? Today I have noticed that filters don't work properly.

**To reply**

I upload a file to a drive folder and when I query the activity of that folder the event has much more info and therefore filter's works in a weird way:
My params:

```
{ 
   "ancestorName": "items/Folder_ID",
   "filter": "detail.action_detail_case:(MOVE DELETE)"
}
```

**Expected Response**

I expect to receive "MOVE" o "DELETE" events, however, I have received the UPLOAD event. In this case, as there has only been one upload I expect:

```
{
    "activities": []
}
```

**Actual Response**

```
{
    "activities": [
        {
            "primaryActionDetail": { "create": { "upload": {} } },
            "actors": [ { "user": { "knownUser": { } } } ],
            "actions": [
                {
                    "detail": { "create": { "upload": {} } }
                },
                {
                    "detail": { "edit": {} }
                },
                {
                    "detail": { "permissionChange": { "addedPermissions": [ { } ] } }
                },
                {
                    "detail": { "move": { "addedParents": [ { } ] } }
                }
            ],
            "targets": [
                {
                    "driveItem": {
                    }
                }
            ],
            "timestamp": "2020-04-15T10:36:58.686Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

The response has info about each detail that isn't relevant. As can be seen the `primaryActionDetail` is "create" "upload" but it is returned in the query despite having queried against "delete"/"move" actions. Any thoughts?

Does this happen because there is a "move" action in "actions"? If so, how could I filter only against `primaryActionDetail`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Considerations:

Migrating Drive API from `v1` to `v2`, changed how single actions are displayed and grouped in the response. Specifically in `v2`, the consolidation strategy does not change the output for [DriveActivity](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/reference/rest/v2/activity/driveactivity) whic will always contain the full set of actors, targets, and actions.

### Approach

A good approach here, as suggested in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/requests#consolidation), would be filtering for the top level once the API call is returned.

> [...] whether or not consolidation is enabled, it may be sufficient for many clients to look at only the top-level contents of a **DriveActivity** (i.e., the collective **Actors** and **Targets** with the primary **ActionDetail**) and ignore the detailed **Actions** in the response.

### References:

[Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2)

Comment: Thanks for the response. You are right, changes from `v1` to `v2` changed how single actions are displayed, however, this is not the case as I have been always using `v2`. The problem comes because in the activity query, I am filtering the **primaryActionDetail** to be *MOVE* or *DELETE* and I've been returned an *UPLOAD* action.

Comment: I'm afraid the filter acts on the **detailed actions**. So you will have to filter in the client side for the `primaryActionDetail`.